# Recurring errors on my windows xp system

Tags: windows-xp, apache-http-server

I have windows xp (still)  and i run on it an apache webserver in order to host my development environment for PHP programming.

But i get errors all the time. They popup and when i click them away. They stay away a few times and then they show up again.

Here is a screenshot to the errors:
[image]

Here is one of the other error screens which appear when i click on "Klik hier"
[image]

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Edited]** Those error messages are generic: they tell us nothing about the cause of the problem. Perhaps someone else knows more about these programs. I have two minor tips:

- You might want to click on "klikt u hier" in order to view more details; if they contain anything like an error code, you could search Google for that—who know, it might turn up something.
- If all else fails, a re-install of XP might solve things. But I can understand that you should not be too eager to do so.

Comment: +1 for "klikt u hier", and -1 for suggesting a reinstall of Windows XP. There's no guarantee that a reinstall will solve the problem at all.

Comment: @RandolphPotter: That is why I said "Perhaps someone else knows more about these programs.", and "If all else fails", and "probably"... but I will change it to "might solve" then. Thanks for the +1 any way, hehe.

Comment: I have added one of the 'klik hier' screens

Answer (score 0):

I support searching for specific error codes and messages that you see when clicking for more information (something like "FastCGI ntdll.dll error").

It doesn't seem like a Windows issue at all though. I'd make sure you are using up-to-date versions of your server software and components. Though of course you may need to be developing on specific versions matching your real server... Look for changelogs regarding your software and see if a point release address any errors you've encountered.

As a tip, when I developed on Windows I always used the portable [XAMPP](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp) environment. Easiest way to run a complete server in Windows. Comes with databases, PHP, PEAR, Perl, Tomcat, phpMyAdmin and more.